# Update CCRC view via windows command line and integrate it in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, updates, clearcase-remote-client

I've been looking for a way to update my CCRC view via windows command line in a non-interactive way.

I'm using Jenkins and today there isn't a plugin for CCRC yet (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5192), so I'm trying, as a first step, to auto update my CCRC view via batch script. I installed Managed Script Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin) and wrote this simple script:

```
cd C:\Views\PathToMyViewVOB
rcleartool login -lname MyUser -server MyServer.com -password MyPass
rcleartool update
```

With this script, in the first execution, the login works correctly, but, I don't know why, Jenkins ignores the update command. In the following executions, it shows this error:

```
CRCLI2014E You have already logged on the server
"MyServer.com".
Build step 'Execute managed windows batch' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've also tried with this other command, thinking that you can pass my credentials with any subcommands of rcleartool:

```
cd C:\Views\PathToMyViewVOB
rcleartool update -username MyUser -password MyPass -server MyServer.com
```

And this is the error now:

```
CRCLI2001E Unrecognized option: "-username".
Use: update [-print] [-ove/rwrite | -nove/rwrite | -ren/ame] [-pti/me][nombrep ...]
update -add/_loadrules [-print] [-ove/rwrite | -nove/rwrite | -ren/ame][-pti/me] nombrep [...]
Build step 'Execute managed windows batch' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've thought in a script that checks if I'm already logged, if not, log in and then update, if yes, only update, and then go on with the compilation, but I don't know how to do that.

Is there any way to do what I want, auto update the CCRC? I can always do it manually, but...you know, it's better non-interactive.

Any suggestions, advice or idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the version of ClearCase that you are using.
Before CC 8.0.1.9, [there is this bug](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI44052) where, in non interactive mode, IBM ClearCase `rcleartool` waits on prompt for login when previous login failed, instead of reporting an error and not prompt the user.

As [mentioned in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014587285), you need to make sure CCSHARED & JAVA_HOME are properly in the [`rcleartool` `config.ini`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929), as [in here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588589):

```
CCSHARED=C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\IMShared
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

Those paths are example only, and might differ from your actual path.
The point is: they must be valid in the Jenkins job execution context (on the slave)

The [OP Alavaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2260948/alavaros) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317272/update-ccrc-view-via-windows-command-line-and-integrate-it-in-jenkins/34321091#comment56524365_34321091):

> only updating the version fixed the problem, now I do:

```
rcleartool update -lname MyUser -server MyServer -password MyPass
```

> And works fine.

Comment: Hi VonC, right now I'm using CC 8.0.1.10. About `config.ini`, I'm unable to find it, where it's supposed to be in a Windows machine? Thanks

Comment: @Alavaros the config.ini is part of the CCRCLI.zip mentioned in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929 (but for CC up to 8.0.0.1: I don't know about more recent CC versions)

Comment: Hi @VonC, only updating the version fixed the problem, now I do `rcleartool update -lname MyUser -server MyServer -password MyPass` and works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Alavaros Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

"rcleartool update" is ignored because rcleartool.bat itself is a batch file so u have to use "call rcleartool -params args" in each line in your batch file.