# Updating a ClearCase Webview via CLI (CCRC)

Tags: continuous-integration, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client, clearcase-automation

I am trying to write a script to automatically update a clearcase webview via rcleartool. When I try to update, the following happens:

```
CRMAP7009: Command "Update" failed:

CCRC WAN Server: Error: Unable to get view handle.
Fehler: "java.io.IOException: Status(1001:hasNonOkMsg):

CCRC WAN Server: Error: Unable to get view handle.
```

This is what I did in advance (inside the terminal):
ClearCase Version 9.0.1.4

1. log into the clear case server, which works
2. cd into my view in a specific vob
3. `update .`

I also tried updating via Java with the following script from IBM (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sites/default/files/support/swg/rattech.nsf/0/a4136394b0ed467285257a94004d05b2/%24FILE/RefreshView.java), but this does not work either. The login does not work here, maybe because of company proxy settings.

The only thing I want to accomplish is an automatic update from Repository, I also have the ClearTeam Explorer installed.

I hope someone has experience with this and will help me

Have a nice day, Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you VonC for your answer, but the solution was always right before my eyes. I just had to set the PRIMARY_GROUP for it to work.

check out my other question where I explained it a little better [Java ClearCase Update on a HTTPS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065344/java-clearcase-update-on-a-https-server)

Answer (score 0):

The [`rcleartool` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rcleartool.htm) does include the [`update` subcommand](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)

But make sure, as shown [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50708156/) to use CC  8.0.9+ (which illustrated a different bug regarding `rcleartool update`), or more generally the most recent ClearCase version you can.

Note, in a bat file, the same thread mentions:

> "`rcleartool update`" is ignored because `rcleartool.bat` itself is a batch file so u have to use "`call rcleartool -params args`" in each line in your batch file.

This is in case your script is executed on a Windows ClearCase client.

Comment: Hey VonC, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately both solutions did not work for me. I have ClearCase V9.0.1.4 installed on the server and the hint about the script is very useful, but as a first step I wanted to update my vob directly in the CLI.

Comment: @PhilippOppel I don't have access to the CLI to test it, so let me know if you find any other element which would avoid this error.

Comment: ok now I think it has something to do with the fact that clearcase is on a https server, I am currently trying the updating with a java script with the cm_api, but no success so far

Comment: @PhilippOppel Yes, you might need to install the CA or server certificates on the CCRC client: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/configuring-secure-sockets-layer-ssl